# Replacing specific row of array inside a dict

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, key

I would like to replace the *n*th row of an array which is stored in a dictionary. The arrays of the dictionary are created with a specific "shape". In the example below the dict has keys `[10, 20, 30, 40]` and each key corresponds to a 5x2 array; when trying to replace the 2nd row of the array identified by key=20 with a `[2,-4]` list, the code below replaces the 2nd row of all arrays in the `dict`. How to get it to replace only the array of key=20?

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
my_dict = dict(zip([10, 20, 30, 40], itertools.repeat(np.zeros((5, 2)))))
my_dict[20][1] = [ 2, -4]
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of many possible solutions:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

my_dict = {key: np.zeros((5, 2)) for key in [10, 20, 30, 40]}
my_dict[20][1] = [ 2, -4]
print(my_dict)
```

Your problem is that the result of `itertools.repeat` refers to the same object in memory 4 times, therefore modifications are reflected in all of the dict's values.

In contrast, `{key: np.zeros((5, 2)) ...}` initializes a new zeros array for each dict entry.

Comment: Interesting, well noticed! Thanks!